# Override extended array size in java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, extends, super

I have a class `LargeCell` which is an extension of the `Cell` class. I want to use same name for fixed array in both classes with a different array size. In cell class I want the size to be 1 and in LargeCell class I want size to be 2. When I try to add prisoner to LargeCell instead of prisoner being added to LargeCell, he is added to array in Cell class. I can override `addPrisonerToCell()` method but it does not seem like the best solution to me since it is copy paste from other class.
Is there any way, to make methods work on the right class without overriding them?

```
public class Cell {
private int cellNumber;
private Prisoner[] prisoners;


public Cell(int cellNumber){
    this.cellNumber=cellNumber;
    this.prisoners=new Prisoner[1];
}


public boolean addPrisonerToCell(Prisoner prisoner) {
    for(int i=0; i<this.prisoners.length;i++){
        if(this.prisoners[i]==null){
            this.prisoners[i]=prisoner;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}}


public class LargeCell extends Cell {

private Prisoner[] prisoners;

public LargeCell(int cellNumber) {
    super(cellNumber);
    this.prisoners = new Prisoner[2];

}
@Override
public boolean addPrisonerToCell(Prisoner prisoner) {
    for(int i=0; i<this.prisoners.length;i++){
        if(this.prisoners[i]==null){
            this.prisoners[i]=prisoner;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest solution would be having the size of the cell as a constructor parameter in `Cell`. This way `LargeCell` would only have to call `super(cellNumber, 2)`.

Comment: Side note: you have a design error in that code where you re-declare the prisoners Prison array in the child class. You really don't want to be doing this.

Comment: You can make class cell an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring another `prisoners` field, you are only shadowing the field from the superclass. You could have the `Cell` constructor accept an int specifying the size of the array like so:

```
public class Cell {
    private int cellNumber;
    private Prisoner[] prisoners;
    public Cell(int cellNumber){
        this(cellNumber, 1);
    }

    protected Cell(int cellNumber, int size){//only accessible by subclasses
        this.cellNumber = cellNumber;
        this.prisoners = new Prisoner[size];
    }


    public boolean addPrisonerToCell(Prisoner prisoner) {
        for(int i=0; i<this.prisoners.length;i++){
            if(this.prisoners[i]==null){
                this.prisoners[i]=prisoner;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class LargeCell extends Cell {
    public LargeCell(int cellNumber) {
        super(cellNumber, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If for some reason OP doesn't want Cell clients to be able to declare the size of the cell, we can also make `Cell(int cellNumber, int size)` protected so it's only used by children classes.

Comment: @AdamBarreiro Good suggestion.

Comment: @AdamBarreiro Since im already using protected in constructor, should i also make fields in Cell class protected?

Comment: @Jabli You don't need to unless you want to access the fields in subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using inheritance to it's full potential :-) . You are declaring `cellNumber` and `Prisoners[]` array in both `Cell` and `LargeCell`. You can simply mark it as protected let them be reused by child class(`LargeCell` in this case). In order to override size of the array, I introduced a method called `getCellSize()` which would be called in constructor for array initialization:

```java
public class Cell {
    protected int cellNumber;
    protected Prisoner[] prisoners;

    public Cell(int cellNumber){
        this.cellNumber=cellNumber;
        this.prisoners=new Prisoner[getCellSize()];
    }

    public int getCellSize() { return 1; }

    public boolean addPrisonerToCell(Prisoner prisoner) {
        for(int i=0; i<this.prisoners.length;i++){
            if(this.prisoners[i]==null){
                this.prisoners[i]=prisoner;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can simply override this method in `LargeCell` to return a different value:

```java
public class LargeCell extends Cell {

    public LargeCell(int cellNumber) {
        super(cellNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCellSize() { return 2; }

    @Override
    public boolean addPrisonerToCell(Prisoner prisoner) {
        for(int i=0; i<this.prisoners.length;i++){
            if(this.prisoners[i]==null){
                this.prisoners[i]=prisoner;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tested it like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cell cell = new Cell(11);
    System.out.println("Adding A to cell ..." + (cell.addPrisonerToCell(new Prisoner("A")) ? "Success" : "Failed"));
    System.out.println("Adding B to cell ..." + (cell.addPrisonerToCell(new Prisoner("B")) ? "Success" : "Failed"));

    LargeCell largeCell = new LargeCell(12);
    System.out.println("Adding C to large cell ..." + (largeCell.addPrisonerToCell(new Prisoner("C")) ? "Success" : "Failed"));
    System.out.println("Adding D to large  cell ..." + (largeCell.addPrisonerToCell(new Prisoner("D")) ? "Success" : "Failed"));
    System.out.println("Adding E to large  cell ..." + (largeCell.addPrisonerToCell(new Prisoner("E")) ? "Success" : "Failed"));
}
```

This returns the following output:

```
Adding A to cell ...Success
Adding B to cell ...Failed
Adding C to large cell ...Success
Adding D to large  cell ...Success
Adding E to large  cell ...Failed
```